# Laravel Query String Routing

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an API for some other developers and I would like to use query strings rather than having friendly URLs.

I'm aware of linking to routes with query strings and making them however if I were to do this:

```
Route::get('route?param={param}&param2={param2}', function($param, $param2)
{
    // we're good to go.
});
```

It would not work as intended. I'm aware I can leave out the strings and do manual checking with `Input::has()` but I was wonderng, why can't I do it this way versus:

```
Route::get('route', function()
{
    if(Input::has('param1') && Input::has('param2')) {

        // we're good to go.

    }
});
```

Comment: And don't think you get around checking and retrieving the params with `Input::has/get`

Comment: I'm trying to cheat my way out of doing those checks like I would with a normal URL route.

Comment: What's the reason why you don't want to use "friendly" URLs?

Comment: The URL will be directly used for validating keys in a database. It confuses other developers when they need to memorize the placements of parameters in a url.

Comment: Well if the order doesn't matter (and maybe even some of the parameters are optional) then a query string is perfect in my opinion.

Comment: I got an answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731266/defining-laravel-routes-when-certain-query-strings-are-present... use Middleware: `Route::get('/', function(){})->middleware('search');`