# Defining Laravel routes when certain query strings are present

Tags: php, laravel, routes, query-string

Say I want to be able to submit a search form on any page that will append a `?s=` to the current url but return a SERP: `https://example.com/my-page?s=foobar`. (I've seen a few sites do this instead of pointing to `/search?s=.*` - not the way I'd do it, but it illustrates my question.)

In my Laravel `web.php` routes, is there currently a way to register this other than maybe using a wonky regex?

```
<?php
Route::get('.+?\?.+?\bs={search}', 'SearchController@search');
// This regex is probably wrong, but you get what I was going for,
// and that kinda highlights why this is not an ideal way to do it
?>
```

This gets uglier when, say, you want to capture multiple $_GET params:

`https://example.com/my-page?s=foobar&dept=clothing`

I haven't found anything in Laravel docs that let you define query string options on the `Route` `$uri` parameter. The recommended option is to just use pretty URLs (`https://example.com/search/foobar`), but there are definitely valid use cases for keeping query strings.

Comment: So you want any route that has a `?s=...` to be picked up by a single search controller?  Is that what you're trying to do? I don't really undersatnd why you would structure an app this way, but you're probably better off adding middleware that looks for the `s` query param

Comment: @WillardSolutions yep, that looks to be the answer. Yeah, my example is not great. Perhaps I should fix it up with a valid use-case. Like `/?keyword=foobar&dept=clothing&brand=acme`, where if `brand=acme` it would use `AcmeController` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Create a middleware (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware)
2: Validate incoming request using $request->query('s')
3: If validation successfull return to next else redirect to wherever or display an error response

Comment: Ahh I believe this is exactly the answer. I've seen others ask this question (usually about the `route()` helper) all around the interweb and most answers are "Just don't do it that way" instead of recognizing the valid use-cases of query strings. I've not yet dug into Middleware, but that looks to be the appropriate route.

Answer (score 0):

That is very simple that depends on the parts of a url. The `Route` class uses the "path string" of the url and you try to use the "parameters" of the url.

https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url

In modern websites you should work with that structure because you get a better URL structure and it's much better for SEO and search engines.

You should use the parameters only in the function you call for small things which you can call over the `$request->get('s');` method but then you have to redirect or you have to work in that function.

So don't fight the framework and work in that structure what is defined from the framework that all people who know the framework know how to work with it.